# TSQL NOT operators in where Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Which is better for performance:

```
NOT A=B
```

or

```
A <> B
```

Is there no difference?

Comment: There's no difference, except, clearly, readability.

Comment: I think you should look for A != B for better performance ... Nah, just kidding ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference in performance (you can test this yourself by running both queries and examining the execution plans). Both forms get evaluated as `A <> B`.

However, I much prefer `A <> B` for readability reasons. Writing an entire clause and then putting a `NOT` in front of it does not make sense. Next you'll want to write `A = B` as `NOT A <> B`. Double negatives FTW!

Answer (score 1):

They are both equivalent.

As well in the output as also regarding the execution plan taken.

Answer (score 0):

They both are the same. You can write in A <> B or A!=B as well. I also prefer A <> B for distinguish the code. You can run a simple Select statement with same filter in Execution plan. The result you see will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

They both are the same but it is your preference which one you are not confused of. For my case I use A <> B.